# Store filepath/image locally on smartphone and upload later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm building a HTML/JS app that I will build into a PhoneGap IOS/Android app, to help a friend fill in in survey forms on her smartphone, store them on the phone and then upload them to a server when she gets 3G coverage.

My problem right now is that I want to attach photos to these forms. My plan was use jquery to serialize the path to the file, store it in localstorage and then upload via ajax later. However this doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way to store the path to an image, and then still be able to upload it later? or do I have to store the whole file somehow?

Comment: I think you can't 'delay' the file uploading, because if so you will be able to download any file from the user phone just by changing the path inside your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Phonegap documentation:

> navigator.camera.getPicture( cameraSuccess, cameraError, [ cameraOptions ] );
>
> The return value will be sent to the cameraSuccess function, in one of the following formats, depending on the **cameraOptions** you specify:
>
> A String containing the Base64 encoded photo image.
>
> A String representing the image file location on local storage (default).

It would be simpler to just put the base64 in the localstorage and get it at the time of uploading, but if you prefer you should be able to store the path, then retrieve data from it and upload when you have connectivity.

[EDIT]

I didn't think about the problem pointed out by @jaay in the comments. What if the file changes at a later time? Maybe it is just better to store base64 data.

Comment: Thanks Andrea! This was a great help!